# Blender Pose shape keys!

Tags: animation, shape-keys, pose-mode

Im having trouble posing my character using shape keys. Most of the videos ive seen use edit mode to modify the mesh. However, I rigged my model, so im using pose mode. But the shape keys are not modifying the mesh when the model is rigged in pose mode.

Any Suggestions? I tried downloading the pose shape keys addon from Blender studio but it seems that there may be a bug in the addon.

Comment: The [Pose Shape Keys addon](https://studio.blender.org/training/blender-studio-rigging-tools/chapter/addon-pose-shape-keys/) isn't meant for posing but for creating and managing corrective shapekeys, which are used to "correct" bad deformations from a specific pose by an armature. I.E. when you rotate an elbow and the mesh bends inwards like a candy or penetrates itself, you make a "corrective shapekey" triggered by the bone's rotation to "correct" the mesh in that pose.

Comment: Edit mode is used on the mesh object to create the shapekeys. Animating shapekeys is then done from the shapekeys panel on the object data tab, or ideally you make controllers for these shapekeys in your rig so that you can access them from your armature in pose mode and animate everything from one place.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)